# How do you test routes with middleware('auth:api')?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-passport

I'm writing some unit tests for a project I am working on and I can't seem to test posting as a logged in user.

I have tried adding a bearer token to the env file, this worked when on my machine, but fails with buddyworks running the tests after pushing.

```php
 public function test_orders_route_authenticated_user () {

        $data =
            '{
                "orderID": "001241",
                "sku": "123456",
                "quantity": 9,
                "pricePerUnit": 78,
                "priceTotal": 702
            }';

        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();;

        //dd($user);
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            'Authorization'=>'MPBtsJN5qf',
            ])->json('POST', 'api/products',[
                $data
            ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);

}
```

So this code gives me error 500. I have managed to get error 401 and 500, but never the intended status 200. Please help

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, are you extending Laravel's TestCase?

Comment: I'm using Laravel version 5.8.17

Comment: And yeah I'm extending Laravel's TestCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#testing) you can use `Passport::actingAs(...)`:

```
public function test_orders_route_authenticated_user()
{
    Passport::actingAs(
        factory(User::class)->create()
    );

    $data = [
        'orderID'      => '001241',
        'sku'          => '123456',
        'quantity'     => 9,
        'pricePerUnit' => 78,
        'priceTotal'   => 702,
    ];

    $this->json('post', 'api/products', $data)->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, unfortunetly, I still receive a status code of 500. When testing with postman it works as long as I add the bearer token to the authorization section. The test will also pass locally if I add the token into the header of the request, but then when testing it on a different device it won't as it no longer has the local database with the token

Comment: Are you able to check the log to see exactly what the 500 error is?

Comment: Jul 22 15:31:04 local php: [2019-07-22 13:31:03] testing.ERROR: include(/...vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/productController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory {"userId":41,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): include(...vendor/composer/../../app/Http/Controllers/productController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory at .../vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:444)

Comment: That doesn't look like an issue with the auth side of the things. To be fair, I'm surprised that it's not failing with postman.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply jwt auth on your route like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
  Route::get('/index','IndexController@index');

});
```

Comment: i think the question is about to test the route having middleware either in API or Web